# Change the threshold for migrated questions showing up on the front page

Tags: feature-request, migration, locked-questions, homepage, visibility

If a question is scored at -4 or below, it doesn't show up on the front page of the site.  This is current functionality

When a question is migrated to another site it is locked on the origin site. This means there can't be any voting on it.  Sometimes / often when a question is blatantly off topic on a given site, it gets down votes.  Once the question is migrated, being locked, it can't get any more votes that may make it not show on the front page.

**Change the threshold for locked questions (of which migrated questions are a subset of) so that negatively scored locked questions don't show up on the front page.**

Do note that the front page is different than the 'questions by activity' or 'newest questions' which show *all* questions no matter what their score. This is just about the *front* page that you get to when you go to the site.

The question came up for "why not extend this to all closed questions?"  The answer to this is that there are situations where you want eyeballs on a closed negatively scored question - and for that to be shown on the front page. In particular, situations where a mediocre question had an edit to make it better (and get reopen or up votes), or a stealth spam edit was done to something.  While these would both show up in the question activity tab too, locked questions are a special case in that *neither* of these situations can occur.  There is nothing that can be done with a locked question, other than follow its migration if that was the reason for a lock.

Comment: Just downvote it before migrating it ;)

Comment: @durron597 I can assure you in the situation that inspired this, on a question that was scored -3 before it was migrated, one of those downvotes was mine.

Comment: As someone who keeps an eye on off-topic questions, I **like** being able to see the [migrated] tag, so that I know it's been taken care of. It also makes it easy to check how it's being received on the other site.

Comment: @Catija there is a difference between [the front page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) and [newest questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest). The front page has an existing threshold for visibility so that significantly down voted questions don't clutter it or crowd out other posts. With locked migrations, no one can vote on them anymore to push them off the front page (they would still be visible in newest) and so they sit there as an eyesore.

Comment: @MichaelT I'm aware of that... I never use the newest questions page...

Comment: @Catija the issue is that a -3 question that can't be voted on sticks on the front page (which is labeled as 'Top Questions') possibly for a day or so on nearly all sites other than Stack Overflow. This presents a poor experience to readers ("everyone here is so mean") and also prevents other, older, *good* questions from getting as much time in the sun as possible. Neither of those are desirable.

Comment: @MichaelT Clearly we disagree... That's allowed. I will not be agreeing with you. I understand everything you're saying but I see value in them remaining visible. The "top questions" doesn't mean anything about quality...

Comment: @Catija if you really want to keep an eye at stuff like that, you probably better use other view than front page? because front page hides some questions you may be willing to see (score -4 and lower). That's intentional,  because front page is primarily intended for new, inexperienced visitors and is supposed to save them from seeing particularly troublesome stuff

Comment: @gnat Except that there's often not anything wrong with a migrated question... it's simply on the wrong site. If the question interests a user, regardless of age, it's still a question and is visible on another site... and if there **is** something wrong with the question, it shouldn't have been migrated at all.

Comment: @Catija I don't argue with that, I merely wonder why you aren't concerned that front page (already) hides some questions that may be worthy too. Given that you don't want other kind of questions to be hidden there, I would expect you to worry. I am only trying to help, you seem to dislike filtering and I point that it happens at that page and that other pages are not filtered

Comment: @gnat Well... probably because migrations on the sites I visit are extremely rare, so at most, they'd take up one spot... which isn't really much to worry about. I suppose if there were a site that regularly had 5+ migrations, I'd think differently but I don't know that's the case anywhere.

Comment: @Catija I am afraid I don't understand. It looks like you want to see migrated question at score -2/-3 but in the same time, inability to see migrated questions scored -4/-5 doesn't worry you, do I understand correctly?

Comment: @Catija On Programmers.SE, about 10% of the most recent questions have been migrated today. We often get questions that are people confused about if they should post on Stack Overflow or Programmers.SE. Many of these get downvoted significantly (as they are blatantly off topic) to discourage people from answering on P.SE (for situations where the migration fails because of a question ban on the target site - and also that people answering off topic questions encourages more off topic questions). So for the front page, its not one or two occasionally - its often five or six each day.

Comment: @gnat As I've said. The sites I use rarely have migrated questions additionally,  the questions that get migrated are rarely downvoted to that degree... so it's simply not an issue on the sites I use.

Comment: @MichaelT I would add that it becomes particularly painful when titles of migrated questions contain words blocked at target site, such as "problem" and "help" at SO ([recent example](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/294727/help-with-javascript-please?noredirect=1)). Inexperienced visitors go to front page, see that these words aren't blocked over there and what's more, get successfully migrated (losing negative score along the way) and, naturally, decide to try their luck too. That looks quite a wide broken window if you ask me

Comment: @Catija if the migrations you see are not down voted, this feature request would have no effect at all on what you see. This feature requests only pertains to migrated posts where the question is scored between -1 and -3 (as ones that are scored -4 and below are not shown as part of existing functionality).